# LaTeX-Suite installation not working

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I've recently installed Vim for Windows 10. After this I have installed latex-suite files in the $HOME/vimfiles/bundle directory (I'm using pathogen). I've configured my `_vimrc`file as following:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin on

set shellslash
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
set nocompatible

filetype indent on

let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

When running `:scriptnames` I can see that the latex scripts are being loaded, but the Tex-Suite menu is not showing up in gvim. I have looked around a tried different solutions, but they have not worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `let g:text_flavor='latex'` should be `let g:tex_flavor='latex'` I'm pretty sure and you should have `filetype plugin on` somewhere in there, I'm not sure that `filetype plugin indent on` has the same effect and you may advise need something like `set nocompatible`. Can't check my own setup to recall if there's anything else essential, `vim-LaTeX` has quite good documentation, have you checked the manual?

Comment: I did check the manual but I was probably a bit too tired when writing the vimrc file. I have edited my original question with the new file, but the problem still remains, no Tex-Suite menu or TTemplate command.

Comment: So nothing like compiling a tex file with `\ll` and the `F5`/`F7` keys function as expected?  `vim-LaTeX` tends only to get loaded with files that have already been saved as tex files as far as I have experienced incase that is of use? Could you share the results of `:scriptnames` here?

Comment: @Dai Bowen Aaah, yes! Thank you! It didn't work when creating a new file within Vim, but when opening an already existing .tex file the plugin seems to have been loaded. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dai Bowen in the comments, I was able to find the problem. It seems like the Vim-Latex plugin only loads once you open an already existing .tex file, not when one is created in Vim.

I simply created a new file and saved it as a .tex file and then reopened it.

Comment: So how did u compile the file @Dramentiaras ?. I mean u save with ':w' and then ?